# PHP: How can I get the values, with 3 minutes each element, out of my array?

Tags: php, arrays

How can I get the values out of my array if there is within 3 minutes apart?
This is my array, $array1

```
 Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [id] => 47523 [date] => 12-02-13 14:36:32 ) 
[1] => Array ( [id] => 65454 [date] => 12-02-13 14:36:32 ) 
[2] => Array ( [id] => 47523 [date] => 12-02-13 13:56:48 ) 
[3] => Array ( [id] => 38639 [date] => 12-02-13 13:56:48 ) 
[4] => Array ( [id] => 38639 [date] => 12-02-13 13:08:51 ) 
[5] => Array ( [id] => 38639 [date] => 12-02-13 13:07:43 ) 
[6] => Array ( [id] => 38639 [date] => 12-02-13 13:09:43 ) 
)
```

How can i get this output

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [id] => 38639 [date] => 12-02-13 13:08:51 ) 
[1] => Array ( [id] => 38639 [date] => 12-02-13 13:07:43 ) 
[2] => Array ( [id] => 38639 [date] => 12-02-13 13:09:43 ) 
)
```

Comment: Suppose there are two pairs of dates which are three minutes apart. What do you return? What about when there are three dates, two pairs of which are within three minutes of each other, but the third not within three minutes of the first?

Comment: I want to return all the dates within 3 minutes, like my output above.

Comment: So what do you return for `[00:00, 00:02, 00:04]`? `00:00` and `00:04` are not within three minutes of each other but they are within three minutes of *something*.

Comment: For that, I return [00:00, 00:02]

Comment: And why not `[00:02, 00:04]`?

Comment: Actually, i would return [00:00, 00:02, 00:04]. My bad. But given [00:00, 00:02, 00:04, 00:08], i wouldnt return the last element.

Comment: What about `[00:00, 00:02, 00:10, 00:12]`?

Comment: This question is ambiguous and not complete ... can you show how you got the result ???

Comment: I didnt got the results, I posted the output im wishing for

Comment: Then your result is not based on  `3 minutes each element` see below why i said so ...

Answer (score 1):

Use [strtotime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to get the timestamp, and then compare the timestamps.

Comment: How is this a constructive answer? What about the rest of the algorithm, which is significantly more complex?!

Comment: The problem statement is not clear enough to devise an algorithm anyways, further I think if problem statement made clear there is nothing constructive to call as algorithm. I accept the answer is not constructive, but same can be stated about the question as well.

Answer (score 0):

Store date as an time();

then...

```
function filterArray3minutes($array) {
  foreach($array as $item) {
   foreach($array as $item2) {
     if($item[date] > $item2[date]-3*60 && $item[date] < $item2[date]+3*60 && !isset($array2[$item[id]]) $array2[$item[id]] = $item;
     }
  }
  foreach($array2 as $item) {
     $array3[] = $item;
  }
   return $array3;
}
```

I think it's very good practice to keep time as integer only exceptions are input and output, it allows much faster work with it.

Edit: Now this function keeps items 3minutes apart of eachother and avoids duplicit entries... I think you can't want more.

Comment: -1: The code seems to find dates that are within three minutes of now, not each other.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thanks, but thats not what I need.

Comment: 1. `date` is a function which can't be used to index an array, and 2. This only works if the items within three minutes are consecutive.

Comment: Another Edit... Good luck with big arrays :D

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you got your result but it looks wrong ..... because they can be 4 different results.

Imagine

```
$data = array(
  0 => Array ( 'id' => 47523, 'date' => "12-02-13 14:36:32" ),
  1 => Array ( 'id' => 47523, 'date' => "12-02-13 13:56:48" ),
  2 => Array ( 'id' => 65454, 'date' => "12-02-13 14:36:32" ),
  3 => Array ( 'id' => 38639, 'date' => "12-02-13 13:56:48" ),
  4 => Array ( 'id' => 38639, 'date' => "12-02-13 13:08:51" ),
  5 => Array ( 'id' => 38639, 'date' => "12-02-13 13:07:43" ),
  6 => Array ( 'id' => 38639, 'date' => "12-02-13 13:09:43" ),
);
```

**Example**

```
var_dump(getDiff($data));
var_dump(getDiff($data,SORT_ASC));
var_dump(getDiff($data,SORT_DESC));
```

**SORT_NONE**

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => int 47523
      'date' => string '12-02-13 13:56:48' (length=17)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => int 38639
      'date' => string '12-02-13 13:08:51' (length=17)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => int 38639
      'date' => string '12-02-13 13:07:43' (length=17)
```

**Output XSORT_ASC**

```
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => int 38639
      'date' => string '12-02-13 13:08:51' (length=17)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => int 38639
      'date' => string '12-02-13 13:09:43' (length=17)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => int 47523
      'date' => string '12-02-13 13:56:48' (length=17)
  3 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => int 47523
      'date' => string '12-02-13 14:36:32' (length=17)
```

**Output XSORT_DESC**

```
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => int 65454
      'date' => string '12-02-13 14:36:32' (length=17)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => int 47523
      'date' => string '12-02-13 13:56:48' (length=17)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => int 38639
      'date' => string '12-02-13 13:08:51' (length=17)
  3 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => int 38639
      'date' => string '12-02-13 13:07:43' (length=17)
```

**Function Used**

```
function getDiff(array $data, $sort = 0) {
    switch ($sort) {
        case SORT_ASC :
            usort($data, function ($a, $b) {
                $a = strtotime($a['date']);
                $b = strtotime($b['date']);
                return ($a == $b) ? 0 : (($a < $b) ? -1 : 1);
            });
            break;
        case SORT_DESC :
            usort($data, function ($a, $b) {
                $a = strtotime($a['date']);
                $b = strtotime($b['date']);
                return ($a == $b) ? 0 : (($a < $b) ? 1 :  -1);
            });

            break;
    }


    $it = new CachingIterator(new ArrayIterator($data), CachingIterator::FULL_CACHE);
    $list = array();
    foreach ( $it as $var ) {
        if ($it->hasNext()) {
            $date = strtotime($var['date']);
            $date2 = $it->getInnerIterator()->current();
            $date2 = strtotime($date2['date']);
            $diff = ($sort === SORT_DESC || $sort === 0) ? $date - $date2  :  $date2 - $date  ;
            if ($diff <= (60 * 3)) {
                $list[] = $it->getInnerIterator()->current();
            }
        }
    }
    return $list;
}
```

**Conclusion**

It depends on position of the date in the element  ....